# Image Data via Ajax - how can I display the image on the Page

Tags: javascript, image, lotus-domino

I am creating a Domino Document via AJAX that contains a photo. 
I am able to get the base64 image data back to the server in a Notes Domino Document.

Data is stored in a Richtext (textarea) field as

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAFA..........." - (this goes on for several lines)
```

I am trying to display on the Domino Webpage using passthru tag

```
<<image id= "pic1" >>
```

in the onLoad event of the Form i try to shove the data into the image element using this code:

```
//Photo Stuff
alert(document.forms[0].photo1.value);
document.getElementById("pic1").src = document.forms[0].photo1.value;
```

The alert is showing the data.
Picture is not appearing.

Please help.
Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was under the impression that inline images were possible using a data URI.

Like:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,
Your base 64 source. . . "/>
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("pic1").src = 
   'data:image/png;base64,' + document.forms[0].photo1.value;
```

Edit: tested... here's a jsFiddle:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/UySAb/1/

Mozilla's information on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_data_URL_scheme

Note:  Josiah in his comments is correct as well, your target tag needs to be img, not image.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an `Image` object and put the base64 as its `src`, including the `data:image...` part [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/VmGLF/1/):

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...';
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

It's what they call "Data URIs" and here's [the compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/datauri) for inner peace.